# Animating multiple objects in Expression blend

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, expression-blend

I created a game for windows 8 app where a box is on the screen and the when the user picks the mode they want to play on the clock starts and images will fly up from a box and the user must click on them to get points. but the problem is I want a continuous flow of images until the user gets 50 images clicked. So what I did was copy 50 images and individually made storyboards for each one and then in the c# codebehind I began each of those storyboards like the example code below:

```
Boximage.Begin(); //Now this is just to start the storyboard
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340848/expression-blend-animating-multiple-objects) article and it didn't really answer my question about not making all of those objects.

So my question is, instead of making 50 copies of the same image and making separate storyboards for each image can I just make one image and set the location and how many run programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at creating a custom user control?  It would contain the image, and the storyboard.  It would also be a good place for hit test logic.

Then you create 50 instances of the user control.

To get them to appear in staggered stream, either use a timer to instantiate each control or create a dependency property on the user control for the start time of the animation.